# How to define alternate page numbers (i.e. roman numerals) for PDF documents?

Tags: pdf, adobe-reader, editing, page-numbers, publishing

In nicely published PDF documents of books there are often alternate page numbers / labels (usually names or roman numerals) that make it convenient to access desired pages directly.  Obviously not all PDF readers observe these, but Adobe Reader may display "[Cover] (1 of 104)" or "[ viii ] (10 of 104)" for pages before page "1".  How can I define these alternate page numbers for documents?

Answer (score 2):

You can edit page numbers using the paid programs Adobe Acrobat and Foxit PhantomPDF. The option is called "Page Labels" in Acrobat (under the "Organize Pages" action) and "Format Page Numbers" in Foxit (under the Organize tab). This isn't something you can do in Adobe Reader, though.

Comment: Is there free software that can do this?